# Display current page inside pageable message

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to customize the pagination message to show current page in a kendoGrid. However, as per the documentation [kendogrid for jquery](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/pageable.messages), the only values I can get inside the messages option are first item index, last item index and total no.of items. Is there a way to get the current page inside messages? I have tried to store the current page in a variable outside, but that is not accessible inside messages option.

```
pageable: {
    change: function (e) {
      currentPage = e.index;
    },
    messages: {
      display: "Now showing page " + currentPage
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
pageable: {
    change: function (e) {
        currentPage = e.index;
        var $this = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        $this.pager.options.messages.display = "Now showing page " + e.index;
    },
    messages: {
        display: currentPage == 1 ? "Now showing page 1" : ""
    }
},
```